# how to integrate Twilio JavaScript Video library in Flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, twilio-video

I am new to Flutter and i want integrate Twilio JavaScript Video library in my Flutter app.  I am not sure whether it is possible in flutter or not. Please i need some guidance.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video  from this official link  it is said that   "Web (not yet)".

Comment: Supported platforms :
Android,
iOS,
Web (not yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video 
example https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/tree/master/programmable_video/example

code snippet to `Join a room`

```
Room _room;

final Completer<Room> _completer = Completer<Room>();

void _onConnected(Room room) {
  print('Connected to ${room.name}');
  _completer.complete(_room);
}

void _onConnectFailure(RoomConnectFailureEvent event) {
  print('Failed to connect to room ${event.room.name} with exception: ${event.exception}');
  _completer.completeError(event.exception);
}
  
Future<Room> connectToRoom() async {
  var connectOptions = ConnectOptions(
    accessToken,
    roomName: roomName,
    region: region,                       // Optional region.
    preferAudioCodecs: [OpusCodec()],     // Optional list of preferred AudioCodecs
    preferVideoCodecs: [H264Codec()],     // Optional list of preferred VideoCodecs.
    audioTracks: [LocalAudioTrack(true)], // Optional list of audio tracks.
    dataTracks: [
      LocalDataTrack(
        DataTrackOptions(
          ordered: ordered,                      // Optional, Ordered transmission of messages. Default is `true`.
          maxPacketLifeTime: maxPacketLifeTime,  // Optional, Maximum retransmit time in milliseconds. Default is [DataTrackOptions.defaultMaxPacketLifeTime]
          maxRetransmits: maxRetransmits,        // Optional, Maximum number of retransmitted messages. Default is [DataTrackOptions.defaultMaxRetransmits]
          name: name                             // Optional
        ),                                // Optional
      ),
    ],                                    // Optional list of data tracks
    videoTracks([LocalVideoTrack(true, CameraCapturer(CameraSource.FRONT_CAMERA))]), // Optional list of video tracks. 
  );
  _room = await TwilioProgrammableVideo.connect(connectOptions);
  _room.onConnected.listen(_onConnected);
  _room.onConnectFailure.listen(_onConnectFailure);
  return _completer.future;
}
```

code snippet to `Handle Connected Participants`

```
// Connect to a room.
var room = await TwilioProgrammableVideo.connect(connectOptions);

room.onConnected((Room room) {
  print('Connected to ${room.name}');
});

room.onConnectFailure((RoomConnectFailureEvent event) {
    print('Failed connecting, exception: ${event.exception.message}');
});

room.onDisconnected((RoomDisconnectEvent event) {
  print('Disconnected from ${event.room.name}');
});

room.onRecordingStarted((Room room) {
  print('Recording started in ${room.name}');
});

room.onRecordingStopped((Room room) {
  print('Recording stopped in ${room.name}');
});

// ... Assume we have received the connected callback.

// After receiving the connected callback the LocalParticipant becomes available.
var localParticipant = room.localParticipant;
print('LocalParticipant ${room.localParticipant.identity}');

// Get the first participant from the room.
var remoteParticipant = room.remoteParticipants[0];
print('RemoteParticipant ${remoteParticipant.identity} is in the room');
```

Comment: @chunhungan  Thank you.  It helping me to integrate in native( Android and ios) in twilio flutter.